# Explanation of 'list' and 'object' as parameter in class definition

Tags: python, class, inheritance, parameters

Can somebody please explain what is the purpose of 'object' and 'list' parameters in the classes Card and StandardDeck? I find little information about this.

Phycharm says this about 'object' in class Card():
*The base class of the class hierarchy.
When called, it accepts no arguments and returns a new featureless instance that has no instance attributes and cannot be given any.*

Is class card considered base class because of the 'object' parameter? Does the `super().__init__()` from class StandardDeck inherited from class Card? I really hope someone can give a good explanation i have been struggling for hours.

```py
def main():
    class Card(object):
        def __init__(self, value, suit):
            self.value = value
            self.suit = suit


    class StandardDeck(list):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            suits = list(range(4))
            values = list(range(13))
            [[self.append(Card(i, j)) for j in suits] for i in values]

    deck = StandardDeck()
    for card in deck:
        print(card)

main()
```

Comment: The `super().__init__()` calls the constructor of the superclass, which is `list` in this case.

Comment: the `class Card(object)` is old style syntax - I guess it was prevalent in Python 2. In Python 3, afaik all classes extend from `object` implicitly, so you can just have it like `class Card:`

Comment: As rv.kvetch indicated, this is very old (Python 2.x) syntax.  In Python 3.x all classes automatically inherit from `object.`  Unless you have to maintain a program in Python 2, don't worry about it.  I don't know where you found this code, but I wouldn't stress about understanding it.  The last line of the StandardDeck constructor is sufficient to prove that whoever wrote it did not know what he was doing.  It appears to be an attempt to create a nested list but it doesn't actually do that.

Comment: "Is class card considered base class because of the 'object' parameter?" What PyCharm told you is that `object` is *the* base class. Of *everything*. But every class that you derive from is a "base class" for the thing that derives from it. "Does the super().init() from class StandardDeck inherited from class Card?" No; it comes from `list`,which is why it says `list` in the parentheses.

Comment: Anyway, Stack Overflow is not a tutorial resource nor a discussion forum, and we are not interested in fielding questions about someone else's code. The correct person to ask is the author of the code. Failing that, try Reddit or Quora.

Answer (score 1):

`object` is the [base class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) (also referred to a `super` class) for the derived class `Card`.  This means `Card` inherit all the functionality and state of the base class (and as others said already this is implied anyhow), and it allows `Card` to override (or change) methods as needed.  Another way to say that is `Card` is a more specialized class than `object`.

Similarly, `list` is the base class for `StandardDeck`.

I would also add that it's not a particular good design.  For instance, `list` has a method called `clear()`.  What does it mean to `clear()` a `StandardDeck`?  It would be better design to use whatever data structures are needed an implementation detail (instance variables).  This is sometimes expressed as failing the [Liskov substitution principle (LSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).